# Match exact 7 digits from SMS in android But its taking other numbers also

Tags: android, regex

no> Match exact 7 digits from SMS in android But its not working properly.

> actually I need exact 7 digits from SMS(like MMID have 7 digit).

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                phoneNumber.equals("xxxxxxxxx");

                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                String s = null ;
                String e = "\\d{7}";
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(e);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(message);


                while (m.matches())
                {
                    s = m.group(0);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + ",  mmid: "+s, duration);
                    toast.show();   

                }
            } 
        } 

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
    }
}
```

}

> In SMS message: your no alloted for the  no xxxxxx01019015xx is
>   8435753.
>
> its taking value from this word (xxxxxx01019015xx) like 0101901
>
> But toast showing 0101901 and 8435753

Comment: Try using `s = message.replaceAll(".*?(\\b\\d{7}\\b).*", "$1");`. If there are `xxx` before the number, add it to the pattern: `.replaceAll(".*?xxx(\\d{7}).*", "$1")` for a safer match. Remove the Pattern and Matcher with `while`. Or check with `if (s_orig != s) { ... }`.

Comment: Message is not static.. its coming dynamically.. i dont know what message coming from server.. I have to match 7 digit only..

Comment: Which 7 digits? What is their context? We cannot help you if you do not show us exact examples. Are these 7 digits always at the end of the string? Is it the first in string? Is it preceded with `is` + whitespace?

Comment: i have to extract 8435753

Comment: Maybe [this snippet](http://ideone.com/D1tirT) could be of help: `String message = "your no alloted for the no xxxxxx01019015xx is 8435753.";
        String newmes = message.replaceAll(".*(\\b\\d{7}\\b).*","$1");
        if (message != newmes)
        {
         System.out.println(newmes);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `m.matches()` instead of `m.find()` as `Matched#matches` method makes sure to match complete input using your regex. `Matched#find` on the other hand uses your regex to match whatever it can (partially).

Also better to use anchors in your regex like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{7}$");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..I did that one also. same problem sir.

Comment: No sir. I added in my code.. then also its matching that a/c no first 7 digits.

Comment: means.. I didn't get your point sir. I have done matching logic above right sir

Comment: Means you aren't understanding your own code. I have shown in demo that `m.matches()` doesn't match anything but the 7 digits input. Now it is upto you to debug your code and see what's the problem. I have to go now for some work, good luck.

Comment: You need to provide what is exact value of `message` variable and then try to reproduce the problem on ideone demo I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Perhap wrapping your pattern to negative look ahead and negative look behind can fix it. Try this pattern:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{7})(?!\d)
```

Result:

> 8435753

This pattern will ensure that:

```
(?<!\d) there is no digit before seven digits
(\d{7}) match exactly seven digits
(?!\d)  there is no digit after seven digits
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR1qQ2/1)

**EDIT:**

Another possiblity is to use `b` to match the word boundaries only. Try this pattern:

```
\b\d{7}\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH0fX7/1)

**EDIT:**

Try this pattern:

```
(\d{7})\.?$
```

It will look from the end of line and capture seven digits.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH0fX7/2)

Comment: Sorry.. In android, we have to add \\d instead of \d. But it also i am getting same result..